# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class textView

Tags: java, xml, android-activity

I'm a beginner and  new in android .I searched but not found any way to resolve my problem across the similar my problem...
I have below Error when click the button that created in main_activity to show details in detail_activity... . can help me anybody?
what i do wrong ?

this is full error:

```
 09-05 16:07:16.420: D/AndroidRuntime(1238): Shutting down VM
 09-05 16:07:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1238): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 09-05 16:07:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1238): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.workwithdata/com.example.workwithdata.DetailsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class textView
 09-05 16:07:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
 09-05 16:07:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
 09-05 16:07:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
 09-05 16:07:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
 09-05 16:07:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 09-05 16:07:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
 09-05 16:07:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
 09-05 16:07:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 09-05 16:07:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 09-05 16:07:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
 09-05 16:07:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
 09-05 16:07:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 09-05 16:07:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1238): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class textView
 09-05 16:07:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
 09-05 16:07:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
 09-05 16:07:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
 09-05 16:07:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
 09-05 16:07:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
 09-05 16:07:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:280)
 09-05 16:07:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1899)
 09-05 16:07:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):    at com.example.workwithdata.DetailsActivity.onCreate(DetailsActivity.java:16)
 09-05 16:07:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5182)
 09-05 16:07:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
 09-05 16:07:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
 09-05 16:07:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):    ... 11 more
 09-05 16:07:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1238): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.textView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/mnt/asec/com.example.workwithdata-2/pkg.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/mnt/asec/com.example.workwithdata-2/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
 09-05 16:07:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
 09-05 16:07:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
 09-05 16:07:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
 09-05 16:07:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
 09-05 16:07:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:643)
 09-05 16:07:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
 09-05 16:07:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
 09-05 16:07:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
 09-05 16:07:16.431: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):    ... 21 more
```

the MainActivity.java is :

```
    package com.example.workwithdata;

    import java.util.List;

    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;


    import com.example.workwithdata.R;
    import com.example.workwithdata.data.Flower;
    import com.example.workwithdata.data.FlowerData;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LinearLayout layout=  (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    List<Flower> Flowers = new FlowerData().GetFlowers();

    for (final Flower flower : Flowers) {

        Button button=new Button(this);
        button.setText(flower.flowerName);
        layout.addView(button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("flowerName", flower.flowerName);
                intent.putExtra("imageResource", flower.imageResource);
                intent.putExtra("instruction", flower.instructions);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }


}
```

and DetailsActivity.java:

```
package com.example.workwithdata;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DetailsActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    if (intent !=null) {

    String flowerName = intent.getStringExtra("flowerName");
    int imageResource = intent.getIntExtra("imageResource", 0);
    String instruction = intent.getStringExtra("instrucion");

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setText(flowerName);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    tv.setText(instruction);

    ImageView IV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    IV.setImageResource(imageResource);


    }

  }

}
```

and layout of main_activity.xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/layout" 
android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

and layout of details_activity.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center_vertical" >


    <textView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" >

    </textView>

    <imageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1">

    </imageView>

    <textView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </textView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: post the full stack trace

Comment: In my XML-files all tegs start with an uppercase letter...

Comment: There's no `textView`! it's **TextView**. Same for **ImageView**

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody... .solved my problem... hope that help another person.

some points...

1.be sure that installed the Sources for android SDK to have autocomplete in your layout that you can be sure from your xml code is true.(experience of expert developr that saied don't use graphical layout)
(download and install  the sources from SDK Manager)

2.change layout code of DetailActivity to :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical" >

     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance"/>

     <ImageView 
         android:id="@+id/image"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

     <TextView 
         android:id="@+id/text2"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the face issue, I fixed it by replacing `TextView` with `AppCompatTextView`